# Printing arraylist elements in textfield

Tags: java, arraylist, jtextfield

Actually I want to show the first element of arraylist in textfield1 and its next element in textfield 2 I want it to keep rotating whenever I press button. The problem is that it keeps showing the last element in both textfields

```
public class Teams
{
    String[] P={"Hi","there","you"};
}

Teams tm=new Teams();
for(int j=0;j<=tm.P.length; j++){
   textfield1.setText(tm.P[j]);
   textfield2.setText(tm.P[j+1]);
}
```

Comment: Besides that your question is unclear, this code won't even compile.

Comment: Post complete code. Why do you want to iterare entire list/array ?

Comment: What is the class `Teams` and what is `Teams.P`?

Comment: @Blip Sorry, posted Teams class

Comment: please correct the code for `textField.setText` I feel that you have missed the closing bracket for the function.

Comment: Does not your code throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`?

Comment: Nope, it only shows the last element in both fields

Comment: has this code been enclosed in a `try-catch` block where you catch `Exception`?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an additional check (If-Else).
if textfield1's text is equals to the array[1] then
do swapping.
If it will be there. It will swap it. If not then that If check will be ignored.

This is the answer what I understood your question so far.

Answer (score 0):

From what I get from your code :

```
public class Teams{
    String[] P={"Hi","there","you"};
}
```

Another class

```
 //Inside some function in another class   
 Teams tm=new Teams();
 for(int j=0;j<=tm.P.length; j++){
    textfield1.setText(tm.P[j]);
    textfield2.setText(tm.P[j+1]);
 }
```

The variable `P` in class `Teams` has length 3. So in the code snippet below the value of `j` changes from 0 to 3. In the case when the value of `j` is 2 the line

```
textfield2.setText(tm.P[j+1]);
```

should throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as the index `j+1` i.e. 3 does not exist for `P`.

Also when the value of `P` is 3 both the lines

```
 textfield1.setText(tm.P[j]);
 textfield2.setText(tm.P[j+1]);
```

should throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as the index of `P` is 3 for the first line and 4 for the second line.

Now since you have stated clearly in your comments that there is not exception being thrown, I feel that this code must be inside a `try - catch` block which catches `Exception` objects. Also this should explain why this kind of behaviour of show the last value of `P` in both text fields happen.

When `j` is 1, `textfield2.setText(tm.P[j+1])` the text to this field is set to the last element `"you"`. Now in the next loop when `j` attains the value 2 the first text field `textfield2` gets set to the last element `"you"`. But in the next line an exception is thrown so the line is not executed so the text of `textfield2` remains to `you`.

finally when `j` is 3 the first line itself throws the exception so that the code after the first line is not executed and both `textfield1` and `textfield2` have text values `"you"` stored in them and that is what is displayed and results to the problem you have highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception when you run this code. Your code will terminate with the exception.

According to your example tm.P.length is 3.

When j=2,

```
 textfield1= there
 textfield2= you
```

when j=3,

```
 textfield1= you
```

and

```
 textfield2.setText(tm.P[j+1]);
```

is getting the exception (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)and terminate the flow since tm.P[4] (there is no such a location in the array)but textfield2 previous value is "you"

So your final result is

```
 textfield1= you
 textfield2= you
```